# Increasing permgen space for Cobertura ant task running from Gradle

Tags: ant, gradle, out-of-memory, cobertura

I'm getting the following trying to run Cobertura as part of my Gradle build.

```
:cobertura
Instrumenting classes for Cobertura
Exception in thread "Test worker" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I've tried bumping up `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS`/`-XX:MaxPermSize` in my gradle wrapper script, to no effect. Is there a more direct (and effective) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was changing the .bashrc on my Linux box to have export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-XX:MaxPermSize=512m'
Proof that this got detected by gradle when I built was shown with this message:
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable, or a `org.gradle.jvmargs` property in `gradle.properties`.